# Error in creating backend containers in Azure Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, continuous-deployment

While trying to deploy my web application in the Kubernetes cluster (AKS) I see that my back end pods are not coming up , they keep on going into RESTART details below :

C:\Work\k8> kubectl get pods

```
NAME                                                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
backend-mypod-backend-766b54f6dd-85v6v                         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    549        35h
backend-mypod-backend-766b54f6dd-j4fm9                         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    551        35h
backend-mypod-backend-766b54f6dd-vckbn                              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    549        35h
```

when I do a describe Pod I see below Error for all the backend Pods:

```
Warning  Unhealthy  26m (x5 over 28m)     kubelet, aks-agentpool-33316079-vmss000000  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.39.67.9:8800/api/healthtest: dial tcp 10.39.67.9:8800: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  8m10s (x65 over 28m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-33316079-vmss000000  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.39.67.9:8800/api/healthtest: dial tcp 10.39.67.9:8800: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff    3m10s (x59 over 19m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-33316079-vmss000000  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Below is the section in the deployment yaml where we set the livnessProbe and readinessProbe :

```
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /api/healthtest
        port: {{ .Values.deployment.internalPort }}
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /api/healthtest
        port: {{ .Values.deployment.internalPort }}
      failureThreshold: 3
      periodSeconds: 20
```

10.39.67.97 - This is the IP for the Load Balancer
8800 - This is the internal Port for the deployment

Can some one pls help me of what I am missing here , I presume this to a configuration issue which I am struggling to figure out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try `startupProbe` instead of `readinessProbe`? it's seems like the `readinessProbe` is failing before the server start. it happens when a server took more time than usual to start.

**startupProbe:** Startup probes are useful for Pods that have containers that take a long time to come into service. Rather than set a long liveness interval, you can configure a separate configuration for probing the container as it starts up, allowing a time longer than the liveness interval would allow. [ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#when-should-you-use-a-startup-probe)

The benefit of use `startupProbe` is that other two `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` will not execute until `startupProbe` succeed.

```
startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /api/healthtest
    port: {{ .Values.deployment.internalPort }}
  failureThreshold: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /api/healthtest
    port: {{ .Values.deployment.internalPort }}
  failureThreshold: 3
  periodSeconds: 20
```

Comment: Thanks Emon will give it a try , also is it better to include all the 3 probes

Comment: yes, you can use all of them. actually it's upto your need.